# W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SSL handshake timed out in AndroidQ

Tags: android

I use https to request data in AndroidQ,it can't work,but I use same apk in Android9.0,https can work

the error like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UCqq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the below line at `application` tag in your `manifest` file.

```
<application
    . . . 
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

</application>
```

Comment: thx for your help,
In fact, when I adapt to android9.0, I have added this line of code

Comment: I guess it may be a problem with my local network environment, thank you again